# Support Multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, layout

I want to make my application support all screen size in my last published build i use `wrap content` and `match parent` for handle it but now i want to generate all layouts that respond for each screen size.
I know how to make this by creating folders for each size and put layouts in it but I ask for there is any plugins or feature that make this operation dynamically without make it by myself, I know i will edits in layout to handle many cases but i want to make it simple by generate layout and customize what I want.
 Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use with weight sum and weight in your xml code

Comment: you definitely should not do that, since there are maybe 100s different aspect ratios, screen resolutions and screen size combinations.

Comment: @SunishaSindhu i already use it but in some cases it need customization in some screens to handle client requirements

Comment: @VladMatvienko: But am designing like that.Then what is the solution for it?

Comment: solution is make 1 universal layout using weights, or new ConstraintLayout.

Comment: @VladMatvienko  but , what about dimensions for different screens like padding, margin ? i create one dimension file now so should create multiple dimensions ?

Answer (score 0):

For supporting multiply devices, there are two ways, one from view side and other is programmatically. If you want to do all operations in xml, you can do it with `RelativeLayout` easily. It has some parameters, like `android:layout_alignParentBottom`, `android:layout_alignLeft` or etc, with these parameters, you can customise your views for multiple screens. 
Other way is programmatically way, which you can do your operations in java side. For this way, first of all, you shoul get screen sizes:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int SCREEN_WIDTH = size.x;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = size.y;
```

Before getSize was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the getWidth and getHeight methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int SCREEN_WIDTH = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

And then, get display metrics and density:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float density = metrics.density;
```

After getting these parameters, locate your views where you want. For setting view , you will need such these simple lines:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.width = (int) (40 * density);
    layoutParams.height = (int) (40 * density);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```